# Где размещать логику приложения MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, логика

Всем привет!

Возможно вопрос типичный. Но не дает мне покоя. Если с моделями, вроде таблиц, вопросов не возникает, то в данном случае не смог найти ответа.

Суть: дорабатываю свою программу (WPF) вышивки крестиком, возникла потребность рисования с различными его аспектами (типы, выделение и тп).

Есть примерно такой код (идею подсмотрел в FastGrid):

```
enum CellBlockType
{
    CrossStitch,
    HalfStitch,
    //...
}

interface ISchemeCellBlock
{
    CellBlockType BlockType { get; }
    //...
}

interface ISchemeCell
{
    int BlockCount { get; }
    ISchemeCellBlock GetBlock(int index);
}

interface ISchemeModel
{
    int RowCount { get; }
    int ColumnCount { get; }
    ISchemeCell GetCell(ISchemeView view, int row, int column);
    void HandleCommand(ISchemeView view, CellAddress address, object commandParameter, ref bool handled);
}

interface ISchemeView
{
    void InvalidateCell(int row, int column);
    void InvalidateAll();
    bool ShowGuideline { get; set; }
    //...
}

struct CellAddress { }
```

В данный момент все действия мыши обрабатываются в `HandleCommand`, а в качестве `commandParameter` передаются `MouseEvenArgs`, чтобы понимать когда рисовать/не рисовать, перемещать/вставлять и тп.

Таким образом, `ISchemeView` изменяет данные модели минуя `ViewModel`, но и не в коде самого представления. В самой же `ViewModel` предполагается выбор "кистей рисования", масштабирование, команды ввода/вывода и все косвенные изменения модели.

Имеет ли право на жизнь такой код в рамках MVVM? Или же надо "отправлять" действия мыши из `ISchemeView` во `ViewModel`, а уже через нее воздействовать на саму модель?

**UPD:**

Итак, сделал как предложил **RusArt**: переместил редактирование в codebehind контрола. Что имею теперь:

- Model - набор классов, реализующих вышеописанные интерфейсы.
- View содержит сам контрол и кнопки для выполнения команд.
- ViewModel отдает класс, реализующий ISchemeModel, в контрол через свойство, команды во View для управления ISchemeModel (сохранение, ведение истории изменений и т.п.), а также "отдает" во View коллекцию элементов (палитру) из ISchemeModel.

Такой подход будет правильный? И можно ли назвать мои типы данных моделью или что ею считать?

Хотелось бы до конца разобраться.

Answer (score 5):

Если вы хотите следовать паттерну MVVM, то у вас пока не получается. Model ничего не должна знать про View, а у вас знает (вы передаете ISchemeView и MouseEvenArgs)

Познакомьтесь с командами (интерфейс ICommand). Часто используются сторонние реализации типа DelegateCommand:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute) 
                   : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, 
                   Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if( CanExecuteChanged != null )
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Команда содержит ссылку на метод, который будет выполняться при выполнении команды, и ссылку на метод, который указывает, может ли выполниться команда.

Таким образом, во ViewModel вы создаете свойство типа ICommand, пишите методы на выполнение и выяснение возможности выполнения, привязываете команду ко View. Конечно, для View должно быть определено dependency property, которое отдаст правильный параметр с координатам в команду (это уже другой вопрос, разработка своего контрола, сейчас не знаю какой компонент у вас во View). Но во ViewModel будет что-то примерно такое:

```
public class SchemeViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    ISchemeModel _model;

    public ICommand SelectCommand {get;} = new DelegateCommand(Select, CanSelect);

    void Select(object o)
    {
        var coords = o as CellAddress;
        _model.Select(coords);
    }

    bool CanSelect(object o)
    {
        var coords = o as CellAddress;
        return _model.CanSelect(coords);
    }
}
```

Также откажитесь от интерфейса ISchemeView, который позволяет управлять View из модели. Это фишка паттера MVC, но не MVVM. Есть много разных способов сделать что вы хотите. Например, подписаться на события модели из вьюмодели. Помните, ваша модель должна работать как независимая часть программы. Вы должны уметь изменить модель кодом. Invalidate правда происходит во View, или оно происходит в модели, а View просто отображает состояние модели?

Comment: с командами знаком. Не захотел с ними возится, так как планирую вынести SchemeView как отдельный контрол в отдельный проект. Invalidate происходит во View. Модель должна вызывать событие перерисовки как всей области, так и отдельных ячеек. Как это лучше реализовать, через свой event с аргументами недействительной области/ячейки и подписываться на него во View?

Comment: и еще вопрос. Как лучше реализовать эти команды. Для логики рисования нужно точно знать нажата ли кнопка мыши во время перемещения, а также само событие нажатия и отпускания кнопки. Правильно ли будет делать EventToCommand (MVVM Light) и передавать в качестве параметра MouseEvenArgs?

Comment: @Salnik Вот думаю, не лучше ли вам все рисование поместить в code-behing вашего контрола, а снаружи выставить dependecy property с данными ячеек? По типу того, как TexBox отдает текст. Для контрола не надо создавать VM и Model, потому что он не работает с моделью, а создает данные для модели из пользовательского ввода.

Comment: Пробовал этот вариант, но я переживаю за конвертацию типов. Так как тот же TextBox работает с определенным типом string, а у меня же интерфейсы. Поэтому и обратился сюда) 

Видимо в code-behing и буду дальше делать. Спасибо!

Comment: Дело еще в том, что в случае, например, с тем же TextBox он изменяет часть модели (ее конкретное свойство). У меня же "модель" это один объект с кучей вложенных (не только ячеек), который требует специфичный рендер. Его нельзя разбить как какой-нибудь Costomer на Name, Address  и т.д.

Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Salnik Было бы проще, если бы вы показали код. Есть возможность выложить в сеть?

Comment: Не было на тот момент по суте кода. Как и сейчас в общем. Возникла другая проблема :)